# How to 301 redirect example.com/http://cnn.com/page to example.com/cnn/page?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm setting up a project where users can get information about specific pages.

How can I redirect urls in htaccess that look like:

> http://www.example.com/http://www.cnn.com/article1.html

to:

> http://www.example.com/cnn/article1.html

It is ok if the htaccess specifies cnn and not all dynamic web addresses.

I tried using 301 directory redirects but I think the "http://" part of it is confusing it.

I tried using 301 directory redirects like the following code, but the http:// part is still confusing it:

```
RewriteRule ^http://youtube.com/(.*)$ /youtube/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/http://youtube.com/(.*)$ /youtube/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This code below works properly to redirect example.com/youtube.com/watch?v=videoid to example.com/youtube/watch?v=videoid:

```
  RewriteRule ^youtube.com/(.*)$ /youtube/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but if the user types in a link with http:// in it then the server cannot currently redirect properly.

Even better, if you can remove the /http:// and /https:// altogether from http://example.com/http://url.com and http://example.com/https://url.com to redirect to http://example.com/url.com/ then the redirect code that I have working in the youtube example will fix the issue for all of the domains.

How can I do this?

Thank you!